# Deleting a multiline block of text between regex pattern using sed

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have a duplicated block of text I need to delete in a large xml file.  I want to keep the first block and delete the second all within the same xml tag.  For example:

```
<!--#if--> 
 -- several lines of text
<!--#else-->
-- several lines of the same text
<!--#endif-->
```

I'd like to delete the second block between the else and endif, and keep the keep the block between the if and else tags.  Any help much appreciated - the script ends up deleting the entire file.

```
sed -i '/^<!--#else-->/ {p; :a; N; /^\<\!--\#endif--\>/!ba; s/*.\n//}; d' test.xml
```

Comment: [Obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Use an XML parsing library.

Comment: What is the expected output? give a clearer example.

Comment: The expected output is output everything outside the blocks and the text between #if and #else - i.e. I only want to delete the duplicate text between #else and #endif

Answer (score 4):

I think this should work for you

```
sed '/--#else--/,/--#endif--/{//!d}' test.xml
```

this will delete the lines between `else` and `endif`

if you want to delete `else` and `endif` as well use this:

```
sed '/--#else--/,/--#endif--/d' test.xml
```

in the case you mentioned in the comments try this:

```
sed -n '/--#else--/,/--#endif--/p' test.xml
```

`-n` is dont print by default and `/p` does the print while `/!d` does the delete

Comment: Thank you, I thought I had over complicated it.  Running it it seems to work, but how can I capture it and output to a new file?  -i.bak does not seem to work, it leaves the two files of the same size.

Comment: Damn, it's not working for me.  If I just run the command above - as it scrolls you can see that the block is deleted.  However if I try to output to a new file or use -i.bak I end up with two files of exactly the same size - nothing is deleted.  I also tried cat test.xml | sed '/--#else--/,/--#endif--/{//!d}' > new.xml  and I end up with two files of exactly the same size.

Comment: sed '/--#else--/,/--#endif--/{//!d}' deletes the lines doesnt output anything, use the last command I gave then you will get the result as output in your terminal then you can output it to a file using `>`

Comment: @user2167052 glad that works for you. You can mark the answer as correct if you feel your query has been resolved.

Comment: What if you want to delete the #else but not the #endif?

Comment: @arya in that case why wont you first find the text within the else and endif block and then add endif at the end